# Expand command argument twice before passing to lua function (like \luastringO)

Tags: luatex, expansion, luacode, expandafter

I would like to make a helper macro like `luacode`'s `\luastringO`, but instead expand the arg twice instead of once. There is a bunch of `\expandafter/\unexapnded\noexpand` hackery that always seems to go over my head!

The output I want is:

```
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
\Acmd  | No
\ONEexp  | Once
\TWOexp  | Twice
Full Exp | Full
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

I get:

```
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
\Acmd  | No
\ONEexp  | Once
{\ONEexp } | Twice
Full Exp | Full
VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}

\def\Acmd{\ONEexp}
\def\ONEexp{\TWOexp}
\def\TWOexp{\TREexp}
\def\TREexp{Full Exp}

% as per luacode.sty
% 149 \newcommand \luastring [1] {"\luatexluaescapestring{#1}"}
% 150 \newcommand \luastringO [1] {\luastring{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}
% 151 \newcommand \luastringN [1] {\luastring{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand\luastringT[1]{\luastring{\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter{#1}}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\MYcmd{m}{
\luadirect{texio.write_nl('VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV')}
\luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastringN{#1}..' | No')}
\luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastringO{#1}..' | Once')}
\luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastringT{#1}..' | Twice')}
\luadirect{texio.write_nl(\luastring{#1}..' | Full')}
\luadirect{texio.write_nl('VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV')}
}

\MYcmd{\Acmd}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
\luastring{\unexpanded\expandafter{\expandafter{\Acmd}}}
```

runs `\expandafter` chain with the result:

```
\luastring{\unexpanded{{\ONEexp}}}
```

then `\unexpanded` gets its argument (without outer `{...}`), but inner `{...}` are kept and the result is:

```
{\ONEexp}
```

If you define

```
\def\luastringT #1{\luastring{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1}}}
```

an run it with argument `\Acmd`, then the first `\expandafter` chain skips the middle `\expandafter` and go to the result:

```
\luastring{\unexpanded\expandafter{\ONEexp}}
```

then the remaining `\expandafter` do the job:

```
\luastring{\unexpanded{\TWOexp}}
```

and `\unexpanded` gets the argument `\TWOexp`, protects it and the result is

```
\TWOexp
```